# ASP.NET MVC DropBox refresh token with Chilkat error failed to open file

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, dropbox, chilkat

I'm building MVC application and trying to refresh DropBox token using Chilkat library.
https://www.example-code.com/csharp/dropbox_refresh_token.asp

When I'm trying this

```
Chilkat.JsonObject json = new Chilkat.JsonObject();
success = json.LoadFile("qa_data/tokens/dropbox.json");
```

I got an error:

```
ChilkatLog:


 LoadFile:
ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.93
loadFileX:
  Failed to open file (3)
  filePath: \\?\C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\qa_data\tokens\dropbox.json
  osErrorInfo: The system cannot find the path specified.
  windowsError: 3
  localWindowsFilePath: qa_data\tokens\dropbox.json
  Failed to open for read.
--loadFileX
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument passed to json.LoadFile is a file path, which can be an absolute path, or a relative path.  A relative path, such as "qa_data/tokens/dropbox.json" is relative to the current working directory of the process.  If you don't understand relative paths or the concept of "current working directory", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory

You could instead pass an absolute file path, such as @"C:\someDir\someOtherDir\dropbox.json"

Comment: Thank you. I cheked path C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv and it's empty. There no file there.  Can you please tell me where I can download dropbox.json file to put by right path?